# Storing a Class reference in Sqlite Table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, rss

I am making an android app that will read RSS feeds to you when an alarm fires.  In order to get a list of RSS feeds associated with a particular alarm.  I have a table Alarms, Feeds, and Alarm_Feeds.  Here is where I need a little help or guidance.  ***Is there an easy way for me store an object reference in a sqlite database?*** That way when the alarm fires i can find its associated RSS feeds, get the content, and have then read back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the object into the database. to do that you can create `ByteArrayOutputStream`  and pass it to `ObjectOuputStream`. Then you can store the it as a byte array into the database.

Comment: ill +1 ya if you mention serialVersionUIDs, because they could be rather important here...